# Does Android de-obfuscation mapping file defeat the purpose of obfuscation?

Tags: android, deobfuscation

When releasing an app to the testing we are getting the following warning.

[image: No De-obfuscation warning]

As per the internet the reason for adding a de-obfuscation mapping file is to get meaningful crash reports and analytics. But doesn't defeat the purpose of obfuscation.

If a 3rd party service can read the app using deobfuscation mapping (ex: Firebase Crashylitics), can;t anyone use the mapping to reverse engineer?  Or is it not applicable for 3rd Party crash analytic services?

We expect 3rd party actors not to get our IP but at the same time ability to have meaningful crash reports as well.

Comment: The mapping file isn't provided to other parties. It's only used by google and firebase.

Comment: thanks is there an official reference for it?

Answer (score 0):

Mappings are only passed on to the people you give them to. For example, when you give mappings to Firebase, only Google and the team associated with the Firebase project can access them. They won't share the file, and show you the right debug trace.

So nobody will be able to reverse-engineer your application with the mappings, since they won't have it...

And if you really care to get meaningful crash reports but not for 3rd party, just don't use them... And also, this way, you won't be dependent on a 3rd party.

Comment: This is absolutely FALSE. While they may not have the original mappings, you can EASILY make your own. Deobfuscating Java code is a trival task. Minecraft modders have been doing this for almost a decade now.

R8/Proguard does rename classes/fields/methods as a form of obfuscation, but if thats all you're doing its incredibly weak obf. The main benefit of R8/Proguard is the shrinking and optimization. Shorter names as obf doubles as a shrinking capability. And if you skim proguard's settings you can see what other shrinking/optimizations it offers.